# Where does WebSocket Protocol sit in TCP/IP Model?

Tags: websocket, tcp

According to IETF https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455, WebSocket Protocol is "layered over TCP". Does it mean, it sits in TCP/TP application layer?

Comment: Yes it does. And thank you for not mentioning OSI.